# Help with partitioning scheme for new Kubuntu dual boot

Tags: partition, dual-boot, ssd, kubuntu

I have a 256 GB SSD and a 1TB HDD in my laptop. I want to dual-boot Kubuntu 20.04 with Windows 10. Please explain what exactly do /var and /tmp do, because I need to do some web developing and want to know whether I should make separate partitions for them. Also, to save space on the SSD, can I mount /home, /var etc. on the HDD, without a significant increase in boot time? I heard that root partition will have to wait for mounting from HDD, which will increase boot time. Besides, should I make separate /opt and /usr, too. My current planning is: 11GB swap in SSD, 45GB root partition in SSD, 1GB /boot in SSD, and 50GB /home in HDD. I have also heard that separate /boot partition is not needed in SSD. So please guide me.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's better to have a boot partition for Linux on your SSD and 512MB will be enough.
2. It's OK to have /home on your HDD (that won't slow down boot significantly).
3. If you don't expect to have many gigabytes worth of MySQL (or any other DB) data there's no need to have a separate partition for /var. Likewise for /opt. It's not clear what you'll be running.

Backup your EFI System partition before installing Linux just in case.

Comment: S. Tashnikov How to do that? I have a windows recovery drive. Not enough?

Comment: A you have a Windows recovery drive, you can probably omit this step.

Comment: Can I somehow use symlinks in case I need space on / and var and tmp are taking too much?

Comment: Yes, you sure can.